# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable 

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I try to call my repository in a Sub Select, I got this error.

```
 IGrpTextRepository rep = new GrpTextRepository();

        var query = new DetailViewModel
        {
            ViewDet = (from gh in _db.Grp
                       select new MultiDetailViewModel
                       {
                           Header = gh,
                           Txts = rep.FindAllLangTxtById(gh.GrpID)

                       }).ToList(),
            Lang = _db.Language.ToList(),

        };
```

My Interface is

```
 public interface IGrpTextRepository
{
    IQueryable<GrpText> FindAllLangTxtById(int GrpID);
}

public class GrpTextRepository : IGrpTextRepository
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    public IQueryable<GrpText> FindAllLangTxtById(int GrpID)
    {
        return (from lang in db.Language
               join gtxts in db.GrpText on lang.LangID equals gtxts.LangID into jointxt
               from fintxt in jointxt.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where fintxt.GrpID == GrpID
               select fintxt);
    }


}
```

Here is the full Error Message

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[aaa.Models.GrpText] FindAllLangTxtById(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Wish I could explain this succinctly...  How much do you already know about the IQueryable interface, deferred execution, and expression trees?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple solution is to add a .ToList() before your select(...).

```
  ViewDet = _db.Grp.ToList().Select(gh => new MultiDetailViewModel ...)
```

That way the initial request will go to the database, come back with the results and you can then reproject them using a select statement against Linq to objects.

But I have to ask why there isn't an FK relationship between the groups and the texts and thus an Entity Association between the two allowing you to just access `gh.GrpText` and get to the collection of texts lazily loaded (or eagerly loaded using .Include()).

As @Doguhan Uluca points out in the comments, using `ToList()` is risky as it will cause everything in that table to be fetched into memory.  You should only use it on very small collections.  The correct approach is to fix your database design so you can query it efficiently.

Comment: I Already have a FK between group and text. . I want to make a subquery with a left join with my Language Table. I want the list of each group text in different lang. If the group text is not traduct for a specific language, I want the result as null.

Comment: I'd advise against calling .ToList() on your database table, that is unless you want to load the whole table in memory.

Comment: @DoguhanUluca - So what is the alternative to calling .ToList() in a situation like this?

Comment: In this case the correct alternative is the one I proposed - use an FK relationship so the texts can be lazily (or eagerly) loaded.  Sometimes `ToList()` is fine if you know it's a small table but usually, as @DoguhanUluca points out it's the wrong thing to do.  You might also be able to project to an anonymous type as this can be translated into a SELECT that returns just some of the columns in the database but you will still have to convert that to a non-anonymous type at some point in order to return it from your method.

Comment: @oonyalo Lately I've been creating views that I later use with LINQ to avoid overly complicated LINQ statements that really don't work well. Any operation that'd require a .ToList() like a Distinct, which also requires dynamic LINQ manipulation in code later, then I recommend using a database view.